# Sum of infinite squares and factorials: $\frac{1^2}{1!}+ \frac{2^2}{2!}+ \frac{3^2}{3!} + \frac{4^2}{4!} + \dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, limsup-and-liminf

$$\frac{1^2}{1!}+ \frac{2^2}{2!}+ \frac{3^2}{3!} + \frac{4^2}{4!} + \dotsb$$

I wrote it as:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{(r^2)}{r!}.$$

Then I thought of sandwich theorem, it didn't work. Now I am trying to convert it into difference of two consecutive terms but can't. Need hints.

Comment: Do you just want to prove this converges? Or do you want to find its sum? In the latter case I suggest warming up by first investigating $\sum_{r=1}^\infty r/r!$.

Comment: I want to find its sum.

Comment: the result should be $2e$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint 1:**
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{(r^2)}{r!}=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{(r-1)!}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{r+1}{r!}$$

**Hint 2:** Derivate 
$$xe^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{x^{r+1}}{r!}$$

Answer (score 0):

The $n^{th}$ term of this series, suppose:

$t_n=\dfrac{n^2}{n!}=\dfrac{n(n-1)+n}{n!}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{n!}+\dfrac{n}{n!}=\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}$

Sum of terms:
\begin{align*}
S_n&=\dfrac{1^2}{1!}+\dfrac{2^2}{2!}+\dfrac{3^2}{3!} +\cdots\infty\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}t_n\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\right]\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\left(0+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{2}{2!}+\dfrac{3}{3!} +\cdots\infty\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{2}{2!}+\dfrac{3}{3!} +\cdots\infty\right)\\
&=e+e\\
&=2e
\end{align*}